# Alternative to groupBy operator in Reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

This is sort of followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185129/parallel-dispatch-of-groupby-groups-in-reactor). Proposed solution in answers is to use the `groupBy` operator. This is generally fine, but as mentioned in its docs, it is not recommended to use with large number of distinct keys, lets say tens of thousands.

```
data
  .groupBy(Data::getPointID)
  .flatMap(sameIdFlux -> sameIdFlux
    .concatMap(processor::process)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Each group has unlimited elements in nature which may arrive at any time. Also I need to limit the number of groups, which are concurrently processed. As I understand it, if I would use the code above, either I would reach the implicit limit of open groups and new ones won´t be opened (processed), or Ï would eventually reach out-of-memory since even long-time inactive groups would not be closed (think deleted entities) and therefore consume some memory overhead for nothing.

Is there some operator / pattern I could use to achieve same behavior without running into above mentioned problems? I originally tried to close each group with some reasonable `Duration`, but then I am open to race-conditions when one group closes and same Id arrives, therefore they would be processed in parallel which is not desired.

EDIT: I was investigating a bit more and trying more approaches, and currently my biggest problem seems to be how to properly manage backpressure / correctly limit maximum concurrency without limiting number of groups itself. Data generation is usually linear but can sometimes produce large spikes I need to limit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to the world of `spring-flux` and `project-reactor` so I am not aware of any pattern out-of-the-box that you can solve your problem. However, you can create your own pattern to limit the number of groups that you create using the `groupBy` operator.

In the example bellow I used the pattern of `int partition = i % numberOfPartitions;` inspired by [this blog post of Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/features/2017/07/04/flink-rescalable-state.html) that decides the number of partitions to split a stream.

```
    public Flux<GroupedFlux<Integer, Data>> createFluxUsingGroupBy(List<String> dataList, int numberOfPartitions, int maxCount) {
        return Flux
                .fromStream(IntStream.range(0, maxCount)
                        .mapToObj(i -> {
                            int randomPosition = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, dataList.size());
                            int partition = i % numberOfPartitions;
                            return new Data(i, dataList.get(randomPosition), partition);
                        })
                )
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .log()
                .groupBy(Data::getPartition);
    }
........
@lombok.Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Data {
    private Integer key;
    private String value;
    private Integer partition;
}
```

When I execute it using `numberOfPartitions = 3` I will have partitions from 0 to 2 (3 partitions) regardless the key that I am using.

```
    @Test
    void testFluxUsingGroupBy() {
        int numberOfPartitions = 3;
        int maxCount = 100;
        Flux<GroupedFlux<Integer, Data>> dataGroupedFlux = fluxAndMonoTransformations.createFluxUsingGroupBy(expect, numberOfPartitions, maxCount);
        StepVerifier.create(dataGroupedFlux)
                .expectNextCount(numberOfPartitions)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

here is the log:

```
10:43:02.168 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.ConcatMapImmediate)
10:43:02.179 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - request(256)
10:43:02.291 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=0, value=Spring, partition=0))
10:43:02.362 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - request(1)
10:43:02.375 [parallel-2] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=1, value=Scala, partition=1))
10:43:02.377 [parallel-2] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - request(1)
10:43:02.388 [parallel-3] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=2, value=reactive programming, partition=2))
10:43:02.389 [parallel-3] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - request(1)
10:43:02.400 [parallel-4] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=3, value=java with lambda, partition=0))
10:43:02.411 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=4, value=Spring, partition=1))
10:43:02.422 [parallel-2] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=5, value=java 8, partition=2))
10:43:02.433 [parallel-3] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=6, value=java with lambda, partition=0))
10:43:02.444 [parallel-4] INFO reactor.Flux.ConcatMap.1 - onNext(Data(key=7, value=java with lambda, partition=1))
...
```

To enhance this solution in case there is no `private Integer key;` available on the `Data` object I can generate the partition based on a hash. I used another parameter that is the `parallelism`. It is basically for a restore operation if you save the values on a storage using a parallelism of `X` and when you afterwards read the same values but using a different parallelism `!= X` you can preserve the values on the same group. So I used `int partition = (getDifferentHashCode(value) * parallelism) % numberOfPartitions;` which is also inspired by the blog post that I mentioned. I prefer this approach.

```
    public Flux<GroupedFlux<Integer, Data>> createFluxUsingHashGroupBy(List<String> dataList, int numberOfPartitions, int parallelism, int maxCount) {
        return Flux
                .fromStream(IntStream.range(0, maxCount)
                        .mapToObj(i -> {
                            int randomPosition = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, dataList.size());
                            String value = dataList.get(randomPosition);
                            int partition = (getDifferentHashCode(value) * parallelism) % numberOfPartitions;
                            return new Data(i, value, partition);
                        })
                )
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .log()
                .groupBy(Data::getPartition);
    }

    public int getDifferentHashCode(String value) {
        int hash = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            hash = hash * 31 + value.charAt(i);
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

unit test:

```
    @Test
    void testFluxUsingHashGroupBy() {
        int numberOfPartitions = 3;
        int parallelism = 2;
        int maxCount = 100;
        Flux<GroupedFlux<Integer, Data>> dataGroupedFlux = fluxAndMonoTransformations.createFluxUsingHashGroupBy(expect, numberOfPartitions, parallelism, maxCount);
        StepVerifier.create(dataGroupedFlux)
                .expectNextCount(numberOfPartitions)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

Regarding the backpressure questions, I think it could come in another SO question.

Comment: This is actually pretty clever and I am mad at myself for not thinking about this. I did not realize I don´t actually need N groups for each ID, just M partitions according to my preferred max concurrency, basically Kafka approach (which I already use, that´s why I am mad). Thanks.

Comment: glad that I could help. StackOverflow also gave me a lot of answers in the past that helped my own projects :)