# Reactor GroupBy with Parallelism Runs on same thread

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I'm trying to achieve parallelism per group, wherein grouped element runs in parallel and within the group each element works sequentially. However for the below code, the first emit uses parallel thread, but for subsequent emit it uses some different thread pool. How can I achieve parallelism for group and sequential execution for element within group.

```
public class ReactorTest implements SmartLifecycle, ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private Many<Integer> healthSink;
    private Disposable dispose;

    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        healthSink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
        dispose = healthSink.asFlux().groupBy(v -> v % 3 == 0).parallel(10)
                .runOn(Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(10, 100, "k-task")).log().flatMap(v -> v)
                .subscribe(v -> log.info("Data {}", v));
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        executor.shutdownNow();
        if (dispose != null) {
            dispose.dispose();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return executor == null ? false : !executor.isShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            healthSink.tryEmitNext(counter.incrementAndGet());
            healthSink.tryEmitNext(counter.incrementAndGet());
            healthSink.tryEmitNext(counter.incrementAndGet());
        }, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

**log**

```
2021-07-27 14:15:34.189  INFO 22212 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.kprasad99.reactor.DemoApplication    : Started DemoApplication in 1.464 seconds (JVM running for 1.795)
2021-07-27 14:15:44.206  INFO 22212 --- [       k-task-1] reactor.Parallel.RunOn.1                 : onNext(UnicastGroupedFlux)
2021-07-27 14:15:44.207  INFO 22212 --- [       k-task-2] reactor.Parallel.RunOn.1                 : onNext(UnicastGroupedFlux)
2021-07-27 14:15:44.207  INFO 22212 --- [       k-task-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 2
2021-07-27 14:15:44.207  INFO 22212 --- [       k-task-2] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 3
2021-07-27 14:15:44.207  INFO 22212 --- [       k-task-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 4
2021-07-27 14:15:54.200  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 5
2021-07-27 14:15:54.200  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 6
2021-07-27 14:15:54.200  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 7
2021-07-27 14:16:04.195  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 8
2021-07-27 14:16:04.195  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 9
2021-07-27 14:16:04.195  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 10
2021-07-27 14:16:14.206  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 11
2021-07-27 14:16:14.206  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 12
2021-07-27 14:16:14.206  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 13
2021-07-27 14:16:24.197  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 14
2021-07-27 14:16:24.197  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 15
2021-07-27 14:16:24.197  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 16
2021-07-27 14:16:34.196  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 17
2021-07-27 14:16:34.196  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 18
2021-07-27 14:16:34.196  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 19
2021-07-27 14:16:44.201  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 20
2021-07-27 14:16:44.201  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 21
2021-07-27 14:16:44.201  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 22
2021-07-27 14:16:54.201  INFO 22212 --- [pool-3-thread-1] io.github.kprasad99.reactor.ReactorTest  : Data 23
```

Comment: I think that one reason is that you are using `Sinks.many().unicast()` and the docs says that it `Help building Sinks.Many that will broadcast signals to a single Subscriber`. I tried to use `multicast()` but I had to refactor your code a lot since it does not work out of the box. However, in general if I use a simple `Flux` (not a `Disposable`) the code runs on different threads even without `.parallel(10)`.

Comment: @Felipe But I've single subscriber right. Morever this just an example wherein I'm publishing and subscribing within same class, but intention is publishing from different places. SInce I thought its single subscriber I used unicast.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad Did you manage to get this working? I am kinda confused on the approach for it as well, getting inconsistent results

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `.parallel(..)` *after* the `.flatMap(..)` operator:

```java
Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
  .take(10)
  .groupBy(v -> v % 2 == 0)
  .flatMap(f -> f)
  .parallel(2)
  .runOn(Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(2, 10, "k-task"))
  .subscribe(i -> log.info("Data {}", i));
```

Result:

```
10:32:33.377 [k-task-1] INFO  Data 0
10:32:33.466 [k-task-2] INFO  Data 1
10:32:33.562 [k-task-1] INFO  Data 2
10:32:33.673 [k-task-2] INFO  Data 3
10:32:33.766 [k-task-1] INFO  Data 4
10:32:33.860 [k-task-2] INFO  Data 5
10:32:33.971 [k-task-1] INFO  Data 6
10:32:34.065 [k-task-2] INFO  Data 7
10:32:34.163 [k-task-1] INFO  Data 8
10:32:34.268 [k-task-2] INFO  Data 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. This seems to do the trick. What i am kinda confused based on the documentation and changing `flatMap` with `concatMap` and `flatMapSequential` - I am not getting the desired behavior with them. Any ideas?

Comment: One more thing, if i change the parallel(2) to (3) along with the newBoundedElastic from 2 to 3, the ordering is lost - which means the approach does not work anymore. What about in the case where i would want multiple threads for more than 2 groups?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71971062/2544163 about concatmap/flatmapsequential. Both first drain the first Flux/group.

Comment: I am kinda confused on the parallel(2) and newBoundedElastic(2,...). As i said if te parallel argument is changed - the ordering is broken. I can't grasp why this happens?
Also regarding the flatmap/concatmap - I am even more confused when combining them with parallel() parameters - i understand the explanation in the link, but i cant combine it with parallel in my head